# how to fix "<function choice at 0x105303320>" in visual studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I wanted to make an adventure game sort of thing and it consists mostly of print and time. sleep statements. but the only if statement with a def statement is messing it up, to a point that is. everything works perfectly fine until that end.

I have no clue what is causing this to happen. I mean with some certainty I can say that the if statement is the issue but I don't know how/why.

```
def choice():
   input("so whats for breakfast, salad, eggs, or fish")
#many lines or print and sleep statements later
if str(choice) == "salad":
#insert if code 
else:
    print("try again")
```

expected - "hey what's for breakfast?" ans = salad. "then you have three options for salads

actual -  < function choice at 0x10de89560 >

the above is what gets printed in the debug console and I have no idea why. there are no warnings or errors that VS code had told me about. I am too much of a beginner to already be getting these sorts of things, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It must be..  str(choice()).

choice is a function.

Comment: They need a `return` as well.

Answer (score 0):

fixed code, choice is a function and requires a return

```
# Functions
def choice():
   return input("so whats for breakfast, salad, eggs, or fish")

# Entry Point
decision = str(choice())
if decision == "salad":
    #insert if code
    pass
else:
    print("try again")
```

[screenshot of code running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4TlA.png)

Comment: I had tweaked what you had suggested and it looks like it should work but it still gives me that < function choice at 0x1061580e0 > thing and I am still unsure as to what it is